# How to get VS Code to show me what TypeScript type is expected in the current location of my cursor, without moving the cursor

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, types, tooltip

Let's say I have this type definition elsewhere in the codebase, i.e. I don't have this typedef file open, so it's not visible currently:

```js
type Config = {
    a: string;
    b: number;
    c: 'cat' | 'dog';
};
```

And in another file that I'm currently editing, I'm defining an instance of `Config`:

```js
const instance: Config = {
    a: "",
    b: ,
    c: ,
};
```

...the 2 emojis there aren't literal, they're just placeholders to indicate where my text editing cursor would be at the time:

- If my cursor is at  then I want VS Code to somehow tell me that the expected type is `number`
- If my cursor is at  then I want VS Code to somehow tell me that the expected type is `'cat' | 'dog'`

How can I get some kind of tooltip/hint/peek or whatever that will give me this info, without having to move my cursor elsewhere first?  i.e. I'm looking for a feature that I can bind a keyboard shortcut to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of there being a way to do this exactly without installing any extensions. You can move the cursor (the caret- not the *mouse/pointer* cursor) to the property name part and then invoke `Show or Focus Hover`, which is bound to <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> by default (rebind with ID `editor.action.showHover`).

To get exactly what you want, you'd need it either to become a builtin VS Code feature (raise a feature request issue ticket), or find or write an extension that implements it.

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.